# How to declare an object but not run the constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

I need a MyClass object for the entire lifetime of main(), but only if some flag `useMyObject` is true.

- I believe that the declaration `MyClass myObject` runs the constructor. Is that true? I couldn't manage to look it up.
- If it is, how can I avoid calling the constructor twice?

The constructor grabs a resource that I only want to grab once and only if the flag is set. This is my code:

```
int main() {
    MyClass myObject;
    // ...
    if ( useMyObject ) {
        myObject = MyClass(42);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Declare the object inside of the scope of the `if`. Otherwise, how do you intend to use a non-constructed object?

Comment: @juanchopanza The object will be used later, so it can't die when the scope of `if` ends. For example I could have another `if ( useMyObject )` later.

Comment: You could declare a pointer instead and leave it null if you don't need it.

Comment: @RogerRowland Would that be with `MyClass *myObject` ... `myObject = new MyClass(42)`?

Comment: But **how** can it be used later, if it isn't constructed properly?

Comment: "I couldn't manage to look it up." - why not, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Another approach is to declare an empty constructor and a member function `create`: `MyClass myObject; ...; myObject.create(42);`

Comment: Yes that's right - you must also `delete myObject` later, or use some suitable wrapper (e.g. `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` as appropriate)

Comment: @razlebe I tried googling things like "c++ when is constructor run" and "c++ object declaration" but couldn't find a straight-forward answer. Since I was pretty sure it would run, I decided to ask the question anyway.

Comment: Just for your info: `I believe that the declaration MyClass myObject runs the constructor. Is that true? I couldn't manage to look it up.` It's quite easy to check experimentally: add an `std::cout << "Constructor called" << std::endl;` to the constructor and you will see that it's being called. In fact it's the simplest technique I know to find out if some function is being called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy way to do is to use `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> myObjectPtr;

if(useMyObject)
    myObjectPtr.reset(new MyClass(42));

if(myObjectPtr)
    myObjectPtr->method();
```

But note that it will require a heap allocation, which may be actually more expensive than an "empty" construction. To avoid the cost of heap allocation you can use `boost::optional` which is used similarly to a pointer, but in fact the storage for the object is allocated on the stack:

```
boost::optional<MyClass> myObject;

if(useMyObject)
    myObject = MyClass(42);

if(myObject)
    myObject->method();
```

As you see in any of the above cases, the code will be littered with conditions.

If you are allowed to change the MyClass I would suggest to just construct an "empty" object using the non-parametric constructor. You only need to construct the object into a state where it actually does nothing, but it should not crash the application if used. That empty construction should be cheap and it is only a one time cost anyway.

It would be even better if you can move the object into a scope where it is actually used and avoid the uninitialized/empty object altogether:

```
if(useMyObject) {
    MyClass myObject(42);
    // use the object here and nowhere else.
}
```

Comment: Cool - but I hate all these ifs, I wonder what the problem really is.

Comment: If you hate the `if`s, use `&&`: `myObject && myObject->method();` :P

Comment: @doctorlove There's just one `if`, and in there, the object is passed to another class (not developed by me) that uses that object periodically. For some reason, going out of scope after the `if` would destroy the object.

Comment: @jrok nice. even more fun if you do it with if-else logic encoded with trigraphs and a ternary operator =P Keeps your co-workers on their toes.

Comment: There will be ifs everywhere the object is used. This is just a work-around for a flawed design.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I agree, but it is an answer to: "How to avoid/postpone construction of an object?".

Answer (score 2):

Yes the constructor will be run when you declare the object.

You could use a `std::unique_ptr` instead and just initialise the object if required.

However, that will probably leave your code littered with ifs, so there might be a better way to arrange the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyClass& getMyObject()
  static MyClass myObject(42);
  return myObject;
}
```

Can even be called if you don't actually need the object but just want to ensure that it exists:

```
int main() {
    // ...
    if ( createMyObjectNow ) {
        getMyObject();
    }
    // ...
}
```